# What is the difference between local solutions, unique solution and global solution in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am new to an ODE class however I had to miss out on some lessons unfortunately due to work.

In the course there are different type of solutions, unique solutions, local solutions by cauchy-lipschitz, and global solutions. I was also given an exercise :
Find the maximal interval of solution of the ODE :
$$x''=-w^{2}(1+\epsilon cos(t) )x$$
Where $w$ is strictly between 0 and 0.5 and $w$,$\epsilon$ are real parameters.

Can you guys give me a brief description of the difference between the solutions and a definition for the maximal interval , with a hint to find it in this ODE ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about the independent variable as time $t$. A global solution exists and solves the ODE for all time $t>0$ (or all real $t$).
A local solution, given an initial time $t_0$, is a solution on an interval $[t_0-\varepsilon,t_0+\varepsilon]$. Sometimes a theorem, like Picard, will only yield a local solution, but you can continue the solution past the given interval. You can essentially glue together local solutions. The maximum existence interval would be the limit to how far you can extend the original existence interval using the aforementioned approach.

Solutions to second-order linear ODE exist and are unique on any interval, containing the initial time, on which the coefficients (after putting it in standard form so that the coefficient on the second derivative is $1$) are continuous.

Comment: So a global solution exists only when the maximal interval tends to infinity ? and If this approach creates maximal interval, does that mean I can have multiple maximal interval

Comment: Yes, a global solution is when the maximal interval is $(-\infty, +\infty)$. In a sense, an ODE could have multiple maximal intervals. The requirement that the initial point be contained in the interval is what will determine the maximal interval (so an IVP will have one maximal interval).